# Apache Groa could not find main class error

Tags: java, linux, apache, hadoop, gora

When I try to run apache gora compiler using  **`./gora goracompiler`**, I m getting the following error

`Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.gora.compiler.cli.GoraCompilerCLI`

Before that I got JAVA_HOME not set error after that I resolved that error by setting JAVA_HOME variable

`OS: Cent OS 6.5
Java version : java version "1.7.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.3.3.el6-x86_64 u45-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`goracompiler` command](https://github.com/apache/gora/blob/master/bin/gora) expects [GoraCompilerCLI](https://github.com/apache/gora/blob/master/gora-compiler-cli/src/main/java/org/apache/gora/compiler/cli/GoraCompilerCLI.java) to be in `$GORA_HOME/gora-compiler-cli/target/classes/`

Check you have `gora-compiler-cli/target/classes/java/org/apache/gora/compiler/cli/GoraCompilerCLI.class` or the .jar from the module `gora-compiler-cli` in the classpath.

If not, compile the module with:

```
mvn package -pl gora-compiler-cli
```